# Issue with chaincode instantiate in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am going through a strange situation with chaincode installed. I have a chaincode which is installed on all peers. When i check the the chaincode instantiate with below commond.

```
peer chaincode list --installed
```

It shows me the chaincode installed.

I instantaite the chaincode with below commond.

```
 peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer0.sample.com:7050 -C mychannel -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "AND ('appleMSP.peer','samsungMSP.peer')"
```

It does not show any error and chaincode container is up.

But when i try to invoke the chaincode then i get the below error

**Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode mycc has been successfully instantiated and try again: chaincode mycc not found"**

**Logs for Orderer**

2019-01-23 06:46:19.427 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 035 Error reading from 172.20.0.19:46380: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

I have seen the logs for peer and orderer but noting much is there. Kindly guide me where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Please check with this variable `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true`

Comment: Can you please kindly tell me more about it? Where should I check it?  Sorry, I just being to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

`peer chaincode instantiate` should have a `--waitForEvent` option as `invoke` does.

We implemented it in the `fabric-sdk-py`